# Htaccess redirect a folder if it contain some folder otherwise not redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to do like this.. `domian-name.com/daily-deals/some-folder/` to `domain-name.com/deals/some-folder/` I created a rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?daily-deals/(.*)$ deals/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I don't want to redirect daily-deals if it empty..

```
http://domian-name.com/daily-deals/folder-1/ --> http://domain-name.com/deals/folder-1/
http://domian-name.com/daily-deals/folder-2/ --> http://domain-name.com/deals/folder-2/
if :
http://domian-name.com/daily-deals/ skip redirecting --> http://domain-name.com/daily-deals/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domian-name\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?daily-(deals/)(.+)$ http://domain-name.com/$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

The `.+` will only catch non-empty strings.

Comment: thanks i modify the rule and now its works on all category, if empty not redirect 
RewriteRule ^/?daily-deals/(.+)$ deals/$1 [R=301,L]